# CFDocument Print Settings

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfdocument

I am passing through custom sizes to cf document including paper and margin sizes. IS there anyway to change the default print setting Size Options to be Actual Size by default rather than shrink oversized pages.

Comment: How did you determine the default is *not* actual size? Also, which application?

Comment: Would you please add the attributes of your `cfdocument` to the question?